# Google Play Console: Подтвердите публикацию бета-версии

Tags: android, google-play

Недавно появилась новая версия Google Play консоли и появилось много неясности.

**Я не могу выложить новую бета-версию приложения, хотя пару дней назад делал то же самое и всё работало**

Вот мои шаги:
[image: 1]

[image: 2]

**Нажимаю на пункт 4 и загружаю новый апк(код версии: 11) и он появляется ниже**

[image: 3]

**Код версии 10 - пытался и сохранять и деактивировать, не помогло..**

[image: 4]

**В "Что нового:" писал тексты, не помогает**

[image: 5]

Если кликнуть по красной картинке с ошибке, выходит такое сообщение:
[image: 7]
По поводу ошибки:

> Удалите этот APK-файл или убедитесь, что целевые устройства и коды
>   версий APK-файлов, которые добавлены в обновление, указаны правильно.

У текущей беты versionCode-10, versionName-1.34, её пару дней назад сделал рабочей версией.

Теперь сделал новый апк для беты с versionCode-11, versionName-1.35, заливаю её и не даёт загрузить.

Менял versionCode на 12, versionName несколько раз делал разные, искал, как можно удалить текущий апк версии 10 из беты, чтоб не ругалось, искал по новому дизайну сайта и всё без толку. Может кто-то сталкивался?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На одном из скриншотов есть выделенный **шаг 4 с загрузкой нового апк**

Надо **сначала деактивировать старый апк, без загрузки нового**, то есть поле "Apk файлы, которые нужно добавить" должно быть пустым.

**Далее нажимаем пункт 5 и 6** и если кнопка "опубликовать бета версию" будет активна, кликнуть по ней.

Далее снова проходимся по всем пунктам, но только **уже добавляем наш новый апк через пункт 4.**

На этой странице **уже не должно быть старого апк**, так как мы его удалили ранее.

Кнопка опубликовки новой версии станет доступна.

---

P.S. я не знаю, какой не хороший человек сделал такую реализацию публикации беты, так как только методом тыка можно было понять, как можно опубликовать новую бету. Новый дизайн консоли, конечно же, "огонь" в плане интуитивности